# Android infinite background loop to issue notifications

Tags: android

I'm currently programming an android app, that lets different users duel themselves kinda like the popular app Quizduel. Therefore one user answers the questions, the results are sent to a server which stores them in a database. The second user can see this duel and answer the same questions too, of which the results are also stored in the database.

Now I want to issue a notification on the device of the second user when he has been challenged by someone else. I thought the best way to achieve this would be an infinite background loop, which checks all X minutes whether there are new open duels on the server and issues a notification if that's the case.

I've seen quite a lot of ways to achieve this, like making use of a Service or an IntentService and I really don't know which of the ways is the best one. I can't use the JobScheduler, cause my minAPI is too low.

I'm sorry if you think this question has been answered before, but I found nothing that met my expectations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (firebase cloud messaging, old name is google cloud messaging) its free up to 5 projects. Implementation of this is very simple both on client and server side. In your app you will have service when you will receive notifications, form this service you can send your notification to activity via event bus and show this notification on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this before, but I think this is much to advanced for what I'm looking for. My app is not meant to be distributed over any kind of app store. I just give it manually out to about 20 users. Furthermore I don't use a real application server, cause I don't have enough access rights on the server I'm using. Currently I got a php page that works as an interface between my app and the mySQL database.

Comment: So you can use Alarm or android JobScheduler (only api 21+) and trigger requests in some period. On the backend you should define some endpoint for downloading pending notifications. [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-JobScheduler/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/jobscheduler/MainActivity.java) is good example for JobScheduler